# How to parse this response and save into array in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am new in objective-c, i have done NSXML parsing, but how to parse this response. The Response is:

```
Array
(
    [success] => 1
    [artworks] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 105
                    [title] => asdasdfg
                    [height] => 0.000
                    [width] => 0.000
                    [depth] => 0.000
                    [medium] => 
                    [list_price] => 0
                    [status] => draft
                    [edition] => 
                    [editions] => 
                    [artist_proofs] => 
                    [displaydate] => 
                    [created] => 2011-05-23 16:36:56
                    [hash] => 98a0b94ad30cdda90f9a8195722869db
                    [artist] => Array
                        (
                            [first_name] => Kcho
                            [last_name] => 
                        )

                    [category] => 
                    [images] => Array
                        (
                            [primary] => Array
                                (
                                    [location] => http://staging.paddle8.com/assets/img/placeholder/145x145.jpg
                                    [width] => 145
                                    [height] => 145
                                    [type] => full
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 104
                    [title] => asdasdfg
                    [height] => 23.000
                    [width] => 223.000
                    [depth] => 0.000
                    [medium] => Oil on canvas
                    [list_price] => 1
                    [status] => draft
                    [edition] => 
                    [editions] => 
                    [artist_proofs] => 
                    [displaydate] => 2009
                    [created] => 2011-05-23 12:36:10
                    [hash] => 98a0b94ad30cdda90f9a8195722869db
                    [artist] => Array
                        (
                            [first_name] => Kcho
                            [last_name] => 
                        )

                    [category] => 
                    [images] => Array
                        (
                            [primary] => Array
                                (
                                    [location] => http://staging.paddle8.com/assets/img/placeholder/145x145.jpg
                                    [width] => 145
                                    [height] => 145
                                    [type] => full
                                )

                        )

                )
        )
```

Comment: yeah..also i guess it does not differ from each other much,he/she could give just an example :)

Comment: You need a smaller example that demonstrates your problem/question if you expect anyone to actually read it.

Comment: it is provided by my client this is the response the API is: http://staging.paddle8.com/api_v1/artworks/get_gallery_artworks?gallery_id=19

Comment: please see the edit of my answer for tips on how to parse this response

Answer (score 3):

The response you posted looks like a PHP `print_r` of an array.

As Terente suggested in his comment, the easiest way for you to parse this would be to have the server encode this array in JSON.

This is very trivial, all your client would need to do server side is to replace

```
print_r($array);
```

with

```
json_encode($array);
```

You will then be able to use iOS 5 JSON framework or any external JSON frameworks (YAJLiOS, JSONKit, SBJSON, etc ...) to easily parse the response.

**EDIT:**

The link you posted in the question comments http://staging.paddle8.com/api_v1/artworks/get_gallery_artworks?gallery_id=19 does indeed return JSON.

To parse this, you will need to use a JSON framework. If your app needs to be compatible with iOS versions below 5.0, I suggest you use the JSONKit framework, which has been shown to be the fastest JSON parser out there.

You can get it here: https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit

Once you have imported this framework into your project, you can parse your JSON response like this:

```
NSString *jsonString = yourResponseString; // yourResponseString is the NSString object you get in response to your call to the API

NSDictionary *dict = [jsonString objectFromJSONString]; // This will return either an NSDictionary or NSArray depending on the structure of the jsonString, in your case, this will be a NSDictionary

// Now to get the array of "properties"
NSArray *propertiesArray = [dict objectForKey:@"properties"];

// Now you have an NSArray will all the "properties" objects in the JSON, you can cycle through this array to create all your objects accordingly

for(int i=0; i<[propertiesArray count]; i++) {

    // get the dictionary for each properties object
    NSDictionary *propertyDict = [propertiesArray objectAtIndex:i];

    // now you can access all the variables in the properties object

    // id
    int id = [[propertyDict objectForKey:@"id"] intValue];

    // title
    NSString *title = [propertyDict objectForKey:@"title"];

    // etc ...

}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

As @Mutix and @Terente Ionut Alexandru points out, its a JSON output. Try this link, it shows how to do JSON parsing in IOS.

```
http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/tutorial-fetch-and-parse-json/
```